# Unable to display IMG on html after configuring proxy

Tags: c#, angular, proxy, entity-framework-core

I configured a proxy on my angular APP, so i can access my EF Core API without any CORS issue, and it works fine.

The problem is, the images are not displaying on html, and I dont know why.

Every access to the controllers are working fine.

I'm using /api/controller/action instead of http://localhost:5000/controller/action

// Here is my proxy file

```
{
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://localhost:5000",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "logLevel":"debug"
    }
}
```

// Here is my html img input:

```
<img src="/api/Resources/Images/{{propValue.value}}" width="110" height="50" alt="" style="margin-top: 4%; margin-left: 5%;">
```

// Note that if I put the src attribute of the above image input like 
localhost:5000/Resources/Images/{{propValue.value}} it will word fine.

I apreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that my proxy config file was missing the following line:

"pathRewrite": { "^/api" : "" }

And now it's working fine.

The file now looks like this:

```
{
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://localhost:5000",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "logLevel":"debug",
        "pathRewrite": { "^/api" : "" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to user [src]="imgURL" in the place of src= maybe this is the problem  that work for me

```
  <img class="pic" [src]="imgURL2" />
```

Comment: the data you get from the api is like this `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgA`

Comment: I got it working already bro, i just added the following line to my proxy file:

"pathRewrite": { "^/api" : "" }